# Syntax to create a heat map with Highcharts

Tags: string, syntax, highcharts, heatmap

I would like to do a heat map but without 'time' and integer as X and Y axis (In fact in the example of Highcharts http://jsfiddle.net/9pJhF/ it use csv with integers and data time) but with the strings, something like that:

```
'Name1','A',3077
'Name2','B',5486
'Name3','A',377
'Name4','B',546
'Name5','A',77
'Name6','B',46
```

I would like to know how is implemented the data variable when we not use the csv or a trick to circumvent the problem with csv strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
xAxis: {
        //type: 'category',
        categories: ['Name1','Name2','Name3'],
        tickInterval:  1,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        tickLength: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0, 
        max: 2
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Name1a','Name2a','Name3a'],
        tickInterval:  1,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickLength: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 2
    },
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/5
- http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/6

Comment: Ok that was what I thought but can give me an example to use numbers instead of dates and then put labels?

Comment: I found two other solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/6/ which seems to be simpler.

Comment: It's great examples but i have a problem with colorAxis. In fact my values are somewhere between 0 and 200 or 2000 and when i change the 'stops' interval like that        
colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0, '#3060cf'],
                [100, '#fffbbc'],
                [200, '#c4463a']
            ],
            min: 0
        }, 
,all my squares are blue. I don't understood.Have you an idea ?